# ¿Cómo unir cuatro tablas que contienen datos diferentes en una sola?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en la generación de un reporte y para ello requiero unir cuatro tablas donde hay una sola columna (npn) en común.

En la siguiente figura se muestra la estructura de las tablas, el campo en común entre ellas y el resultado esperado.
[image: Tablas fuentes y resultado esperado]

He construido la siguiente sentencia pero no obtengo el resultado esperado.

```
<pre><code>
SELECT
    a.npn, a.direccion,
    b.nit AS acuenit, b.nuiu AS acuenuiu, b.estrato AS acuestrat,
    c.nit AS alcanit, c.nuiu AS alcanuiu, c.estrato AS alcaestrat,
    d.nit AS aseonit, d.nuiu AS aseonuiu, d.estrato AS aseoestrat
FROM cata a
    LEFT JOIN acue b ON a.npn = b.npn
    LEFT JOIN alca c ON a.npn = c.npn
    LEFT JOIN aseo d ON a.npn = d.npn;
</code></pre>
```

De antemano, muchas gracias por su atención y apoyo.

Estos son otros valores que contiene la tabla, donde no hay relación alguna entre las columnas "nuiu" y "estrato".
[image: Valores de tablas modificados]

Comment: El problema es que como solo estás haciendo el JOIN por un solo ID, no hay ninguna forma de que el DBMS sepa a qué línea de una tabla A asignar a cada línea de la tabla B (o C, o D, o etc...) Dejame intentar una query, y me dices si te funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuación publico una alternativa de solución a la pregunta planteada, la cual fue elaborada por "**zagato.gekko**" a quién agradezco por su apoyo y colaboración.

```
WITH 
t1 AS (
    SELECT cata.npn, cata.direccion, acue.nit, acue.nuiu, acue.estrato, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID
    FROM cata INNER JOIN acue ON cata.npn = acue.npn
),
t2 AS (
    SELECT cata.npn, cata.direccion, alca.nit, alca.nuiu, alca.estrato, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID
    FROM cata INNER JOIN alca ON cata.npn = alca.npn
),
t3 AS (
    SELECT cata.npn, cata.direccion, aseo.nit, aseo.nuiu, aseo.estrato, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID
    FROM cata INNER JOIN aseo ON cata.npn = aseo.npn
)

SELECT 
  t3.npn, t3.direccion,
  t1.nit AS acuenit, t1.nuiu AS acuenuiu, t1.estrato AS acuestrat,
  t2.nit AS alcanit, t2.nuiu AS alcanuiu, t2.estrato AS alcaestrat,
  t3.nit AS aseonit, t3.nuiu AS aseonuiu, t3.estrato AS aseoestrat
FROM t3
  FULL JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t3.id
  FULL JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t3.id;
```

Dado que "aseo" (t3), es la tabla que tiene el mayor número de filas, se debe de colocar de primero en el FROM para que fije el número máximo de filas en el resultado. Por tanto, este orden depende de la tabla que tenga el mayor número de filas.

A continuación muestro el resultado de la consulta.

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Answer (score 1):

Jam, es importante conocer las diferencias entre los INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN y RIGHT JOIN. El problema que estabas teniendo es que estabas juntando las tablas por una única columna, cuando en realidad, tendrías que unirlas por varias, como la solución que incluyo abajo. También debes saber que los join son un **producto cartesiano** y por eso recibías muchas más líneas.

Aquí está la sentencia que necesitas:

```
   SELECT  a.npn ,
            a.direccion ,
            b.nit AS acuenit ,
            b.nuiu AS acuenuiu ,
            b.estrato AS acuestrat ,
            c.nit AS alcanit ,
            c.nuiu AS alcanuiu ,
            c.estrato AS alcaestrat ,
            d.nit AS aseonit ,
            d.nuiu AS aseonuiu ,
            d.estrato AS aseoestrat
    FROM    cata  a
            INNER JOIN aseo d ON d.npn = a.npn
            LEFT JOIN acue  b ON a.npn = b.npn
                                    AND b.estrato = d.estrato
                                    AND b.nuiu = d.nuiu
            LEFT JOIN alca c ON c.npn = b.npn
                                 AND c.nuiu = b.nuiu
                                 AND c.estrato = b.estrato
```

Comment: Arriel, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La acabo de probar y soluciona el problema planteado, pero quisiera saber que pasaría si se adiciona otro registro en las tablas "acue" y "alca", esta sentencia debería variar?

Comment: También cabe aclarar que los registros de las columnas "nuiu" y "estrato" no tienen relación alguna en las tres tablas. Aunque en este ejemplo coinciden pero ellos pueden ser otros valores.

Comment: Hola Jam. Excelente pregunta. Intenta ingresar los registros y nos cuentas si la consulta cambia. Acerca de los otros registros, tienes razón. En caso que hayan  más registros, tal vez haya que cambiar la consulta dependiendo del resultado que desees obtener

Comment: Ya cambié los valores y la sentencia no funciona. En el planteamiento de la pregunta, cargué una imagen con los nuevos valores. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    d.prestamo_codigo, 
    d.cuota, 
    d.cuotavalor, 
    d.fechavence, 
    d.estatus, 
    d.detalle_descripcion, 
    d.prestamo_codigo_recibo, 
    d.vendor_id, 
    d.tipo_operacion, 
    p.prestamo_codigo, 
    p.cliente_id, 
    p.prestamo_id, 
    c.cliente_id, 
    c.cliente_nombre, 
    c.cliente_apellido, 
    c.cliente_telefono, 
    c.cliente_dni
FROM detalle AS d
INNER JOIN prestamo AS p
ON d.prestamo_codigo = p.prestamo_codigo
INNER JOIN cliente AS c
ON p.cliente_id = c.cliente_id
WHERE d.fechavence BETWEEN CAST('$fechainicio' AS DATE) 
AND CAST('$fechafinal' AS DATE) AND d.tipo_operacion=1 AND d.estatus<>3 AND d.vendor_id='$vendorid'
ORDER BY c.cliente_nombre DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: Describe cómo esta consulta responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.